# How to update rows in db and delete left overs where id = 1234

Tags: postgresql

I have a data table with 3 columns. Datable table Named Usertable with columns labeled UserID, UserFavFood, UsersFavSport. Each column has many rows (+100). I would like to search the UserID where UserID = 1234, update rows that need to be updated, and delete the remainder/non updated rows where UserID = 1234. Is it faster to just delete all UserID=1234 and then repopulate it with new info or is there a way to update where UserID = 1234 and delete remaining rows that UserID = 1234?

I'm using PostgresSQL and I've tried deleting and reinserting but I am doing something wrong.

```
DELETE FROM Usertable WHERE UserID = '1234'
AND
INSERT into Usertable(UserID, UserFavFood, UsersFavSport)
VALUES('1234', 'Chicken', 'Baseball')
```

Is it possible to send the values in Lists of three? As in 
Values = ['1234', 'Chicken', 'baseball'],['1234', 'Cheese', 'Soccer']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres 8.2 or later the `VALUES` clause can take multiple tuples:

```
INSERT INTO Usertable (UserID, UserFavFood, UsersFavSport)
VALUES
    ('1234', 'Chicken', 'Baseball'),
    ('1234', 'Cheese', 'Soccer');
```

Regarding executing the delete and insert together, you would have to use a transaction as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just do that then. I appreciate it.